# Block/Theme not 'return'ing $output

Tags: php, drupal-6, drupal-modules, drupal-hooks

This is the issue.

I have a block called 'User Favorites Block'
It's placed in the region 'First Sidebar'
'First Sidebar' appears on the front-page.
The function is supposed to grab the data from the f25_favorites table and list them inside the block. Right now the table is an empty array.
When I `return $output`, none of my divs or anything are output.
When I do `print($output)`, everything is displayed.

This is my test code to show that my 'if' statement is returning true. http://d.pr/zDph

```php
/*
 * f25_favorites_my_favorites theme
 */
function theme_f25_favorites_my_favorites($mypaths) {
  dsm($mypaths);
  print_r(count($mypaths));
  $output .= 'n<div id="f25-favorites">n';
    $output .= '<div id="f25-favorites-list">n';
      if (count($mypaths) == 0) {
        $output .= "No favorites have been added";
        print "No favorites have been added";
      }
      else {
        foreach ($mypaths as $indpath) {
          $output .= l($indpath->title, $indpath->path, $attributes = array());
        }
      }
    $output .= '</div>n';
    $output .= '<div id="f25-favorites-add">n';
    $output .= '</div>n';
  $output .= 'n</div>n';
  return $output;
}
```

This outputs this: http://d.pr/Uhrs
[image: IF test]

*Note the 0 on the top left, that's the output of the 'count()'

And the print of the text within the 'if'*

So, this is my theme:

```php
/*
 * f25_favorites_my_favorites theme
 */
function theme_f25_favorites_my_favorites($mypaths) {
  /*dsm($mypaths);
  print_r(count($mypaths));*/
  $output .= '\n<div id="f25-favorites">\n';
    $output .= '<div id="f25-favorites-list">\n';
      if (count($mypaths) == 0) {
        $output .= "No favorites have been added";
      }
      else {
        foreach ($mypaths as $indpath) {
          $output .= l($indpath->title, $indpath->path, $attributes = array());
        }
      }
    $output .= '</div>\n';
    $output .= '<div id="f25-favorites-add">\n';
    $output .= '</div>\n';
  $output .= '\n</div>\n';
  return $output;
}
```

It's called with this hook_theme() function:

```php
/*
 * Implentation of hook_theme().
 */
function f25_favorites_theme () {
  return array(
    'f25_favorites_my_favorites' => array (
    'arguments' => array ('mypaths' => array())
   ),
  );
}
```

Which is called with this hook_block() function:

```php
/*
 * Implementation of hook_block().
 *
 */
function f25_favorites_block($op = 'list', $delta = 0, $edit = array()) {
  if ($op == 'list') {
    $blocks = array();
    $blocks['f25-favorites'] = array(
      'info' => t('User Favorites Block'),
      'cache' => BLOCK_NO_CACHE,
    );
    return $blocks;
  }

  if ($op == 'view') {
    switch ($delta) {
      case 0:
        $mypaths = f25_favorites_user_favorites();
        $block = array(
          'subject' => t('User Favorites Block'),
          'content' => theme_f25_favorites_my_favorites($mypaths)
        );
      return $block;
    };
  }
}
```

### **Noteworthy**

My theme is a 'Sub-theme' of a theme called 'Zen'
Zen has a block.tpl.php which looks like this: http://d.pr/AaO1

Here is the full code of my module: http://d.pr/cGqc

Comment: What does `f25_favorites_user_favorites()` return? Your theme handler is obviously getting an empty array, so check why it's being passed that empty array.

Comment: Because right now I haven't persisted any data within that array yet. Right now it should be outputting the 'If' statement but instead it's outputting nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be a region-related problem. Try switching to Garland and add the block to a plain old Garland region, and see if it appears.

If you see it in Garland then make sure your sub-theme really is defining that "First Sidebar" region and then actually printing its variable in the tpl files.

(FWIW I tried your code on Garland and it displays the block fine.)

Also, you might want to change your function call from:

```
theme_f25_favorites_my_favorites($mypaths)
```

to:

```
theme('f25_favorites_my_favorites', $mypaths)
```

...if you want to keep the code flexible (i.e. have Drupal call any preprocess functions and allow other people, or yourself in the future, to override the template's output)

Comment: Woops! I forgot to change that back! _facepalm_ I actually only switched to that to bypass the theme call for debugging reasons. Thanks for reminding me though.

Comment: I'm going to test what you said first thing in the morning.

Comment: You are indeed correct; I got the same results. How should I go about fixing this region problem? What should I look for?

Comment: In your sub-theme's .info file you should have a line with something like `regions[sidebar_first]  = First sidebar`. The token between the square brackets ("machine name", I suppose) is what will become the name of the actual PHP variable in your page.tpl. So, make sure your page template has the respective `<?php print $sidebar_first; ?>` bit of code wherever it's supposed to be. Also, make sure your sub-theme has a unique name (particularly, make sure it's not named the same as another theme or module). And remember to clear the caches whenever you modify the theme's .info and stuff

Comment: It's weird, everything is in the right place as far I can see. This is my page.tpl.php - http://d.pr/a3ZM, and this is my theme's info - http://d.pr/gEGB

Comment: You sure the content is going through page.tpl.php? Like, if you put something directly in the page.tpl.php file, do you then see it rendered? Because it could be that there's another tpl being called instead of page.tpl.php (maybe a custom page-front.tpl.php that isn't printing the sidebar or something like that?).

Comment: I'm not quite sure; There's something that makes that sidebar not render properly; Apparently I had an older version of that dev site, so I updated it and I didn't see the problem anymore. I'm not sure what it was exactly but I'll mark your answer as the correct one.